# Error in Qt 5.9.1 SQLite Vacuum?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

hello I have a small app in Qt C++ / SQLite was working nicely on Qt 5.6.2 and I did upgrade to Qt 5.9.1 and the problem is i get runtime errors when i try to VACUUM my db 
note that all queries works except vacuum :( and it works without error on Qt 5.6.2

### relevant code

```
QString msql::sqlExec(QString sqlCmd)
{
    query->clear();
    QString value;

    if (!query->exec(sqlCmd))
    {
        mDebug() << sqlCmd << query->lastError().text();
    }
    else if (!query->first())
    {
        //mDebug() << "not valid query: " << sqlCmd << query->isSelect();
        mDebug() << query->lastError().text();
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        value = query->value(0).toString();
    }
    query->finish();
    return value;
}
```

and

```
bool msql::vacuum()
{
    QStringList tables = db.tables(QSql::AllTables);
    int x = 1;
    int y = tables.count();
    foreach (QString table, tables)
    {
        sqlExec(QString("VACUUM `%1`").arg(table));
        emit progress(QString("Optimizing table %1/%2:%3").arg(x).arg(y).arg(table));
        if (killLoopFlag_)
            return false;
        x++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I get this errors

---

```
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `visits`" "unknown database `visits` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `investigations`" "unknown database `investigations` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `credentials`" "unknown database `credentials` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `siblings`" "unknown database `siblings` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `surgicalNotes`" "unknown database `surgicalNotes` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `metadata`" "unknown database `metadata` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `drugs`" "unknown database `drugs` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `deceased`" "unknown database `deceased` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `visitPrices`" "unknown database `visitPrices` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `conditions`" "unknown database `conditions` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `conditions_patients`" "unknown database `conditions_patients` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `perinatal`" "unknown database `perinatal` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `development`" "unknown database `development` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `obgyn`" "unknown database `obgyn` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `patients`" "unknown database `patients` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `agendaView`" "unknown database `agendaView` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `registerView`" "unknown database `registerView` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `sqlite_master`" "unknown database `sqlite_master` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `SERVICES`" "unknown database `SERVICES` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `defaultDoses`" "unknown database `defaultDoses` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `allergies`" "unknown database `allergies` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `complaints`" "unknown database `complaints` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `diagnoses`" "unknown database `diagnoses` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `dictionary`" "unknown database `dictionary` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `doses`" "unknown database `doses` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `surgeries`" "unknown database `surgeries` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `investigations`" "unknown database `investigations` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `jobs`" "unknown database `jobs` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `places`" "unknown database `places` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `placeOfBirth`" "unknown database `placeOfBirth` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `expander`" "unknown database `expander` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `drugs`" "unknown database `drugs` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `diet`" "unknown database `diet` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `sqlite_master`" "unknown database `sqlite_master` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `drugsIndex`" "unknown database `drugsIndex` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `metadata`" "unknown database `metadata` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString) 
Debug:[2017-07-17 02:51 AM] "VACUUM `sqlite_master`" "unknown database `sqlite_master` Unable to execute statement" (..\qtemr\msql.cpp:16) class QString __thiscall msql::sqlExec(class QString)
```

Answer (score 3):

`VACUUM` is applied not to specific tables, but to a whole database. You used to append table names that were ignored by the `VACUUM` command. Since you upgraded Qt, you've upgraded also SQLite drivers. From the [SQLite site](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html):

> Compatibility Warning: The ability to vacuum attached databases was added in version 3.15.0 (2016-10-14). Prior to that, a schema-name added to the VACUUM statement would be silently ignored and the "main" schema would be vacuumed.

"Schema-name" here is a name of database. So you can just keep a string

```
sqlExec("VACUUM");
```

Comment: Thanks alot I did actually removed to table name but then I lost the ability to track vacuum progress is there any way around that !?

Comment: Your "vacuum progress" was just the same vacuum operation executed many times. I doubt that you can track this operation.